# Draw complex drawable in api lower than 23

Tags: java, android, drawable, android-drawable, xml-drawable

I'm trying to draw drawable consisting of circle and rectangle. It's working fine while api is set to 23. I noticed that following attributes of 'item' have been added in newest api: height, gravity, weight. Is it possible to get the effect in older sdk?

**Drawable:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:height="5dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:left="5dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <size
                android:width="50dp"
                android:height="5dp" />
            <solid android:color="#125572" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item
        android:width="20dp"
        android:height="20dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical">
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <solid android:color="#125572" />
            <size
                android:width="20dp"
                android:height="20dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

**Image using api 23:**

[image]

**Image using api 22:**

[image]

Comment: why dont you use a `ShapeDrawable` with a custom `Shape` object passed to ?

Answer (score -3):

I know this question is quite old but I solved this problem and maybe it is useful for someone even now.

For the solution I created two classes.

One class called MyLayerDrawable that extends LayerDrawable. The important thing to keep in mind about this class is that you can get the top and the left insets for each layer.

```
public class MyLayerDrawable extends LayerDrawable{


private List<Layer> layers;

//some code here

public static class Layer{
    private Drawable drawable;
    private int topInset;
    private int leftInset;
    public Layer(Drawable drawable,int topInset,int leftInset){
        this.leftInset=leftInset;
        this.drawable=drawable;
        this.topInset=topInset;
    }
    public Drawable getDrawable(){
        return drawable;
    }
    public int getTopInset(){
        return topInset;
    }
    public int getLeftInset(){return leftInset;}
}
```

The second class I created is called MyImageViewPatch that owns an ImageView.
The only public method of this class is setImageMyLayerDrawable(MyLayerDrawable layerDrawable). This method delegates setting the image drawable to the ImageView that it owns:

```
public void setImageMyLayerDrawable(MyLayerDrawable layerDrawable){
    imageView.setImageDrawable(layerDrawable);

}
```

But before calling the setImageDrawable method an observer object has been added to the ImageView in the MyImageViewPatch constructor. This observer is called before drawing the Drawable in the ImageView:

```
        imageView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnPreDrawListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onPreDraw() {
            MyLayerDrawable layerDrawable=(MyLayerDrawable)imageView.getDrawable();
            int numberOfLayers=layerDrawable.getNumberOfLayers();
            Drawable drawable;
            Rect bounds;


            for(int i=0;i<numberOfLayers;i++){//for each layer
                drawable=layerDrawable.getDrawable(i);
                bounds=drawable.getBounds();
                bounds.top=layerDrawable.getLayer(i).getTopInset();
                bounds.left=layerDrawable.getLayer(i).getLeftInset();
                if(drawable.getIntrinsicHeight()<bounds.height()){
                    bounds.bottom=drawable.getIntrinsicHeight()+layerDrawable.getLayer(i).getTopInset();

                }
                if(drawable.getIntrinsicWidth()<bounds.width()){
                    bounds.right=drawable.getIntrinsicWidth()+layerDrawable.getLayer(i).getLeftInset();
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
```

As you can see before drawing the MyLayerDrawable the bounds for each Layer are adjusted based on the left and top insets; this is the key part to get the drawables drawn in the correct size instead of stretched.

Here is the shapes xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item
    android:height="5dp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:left="5dp"
    android:top="8dp">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <size
            android:width="50dp"
            android:height="5dp" />
        <solid android:color="#125572" />
    </shape>
</item>

<item
android:width="20dp"
android:height="20dp">
<shape android:shape="oval">
    <solid android:color="#125572" />
    <size
        android:width="20dp"
        android:height="20dp" />
</shape>
</item>


</layer-list>
```

To centre the rectangle vertically I used android:top="8dp" instead of android:gravity="center_vertical".

Here is the code for the Main Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ImageView iv=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    MyLayerDrawable myLayerDrawable=MyLayerDrawable.Builder.build(getApplicationContext(),R.drawable.layer_d_example);
    MyImageViewPatch myImageViewPatch=new MyImageViewPatch(iv);
    myImageViewPatch.setImageMyLayerDrawable(myLayerDrawable);

}
```

}

I have the complete code in github. You may check it out: https://github.com/marcosbses/my_layout_drawable.git